# pluging installed but not showing in WP-admin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-thesis-theme

I have installed a plugin in my word press by add new plugin it got uploaded 100% and got a page that "are you sure do you want to add this" try again.

after that  tried filezila and plugin uploaded in the plugin folder but again it not showing in WP-admin

i am not understading what is the problem?
please solve my problem

Comment: Please check the permissions in plugin folder and try it again

Answer (score 1):

Check that the plug-in is compatible with the version of your wordpress